# Как вносить данные в гугл таблицы с python бота

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Как вносить данные в гугл таблицу, чтоб каждое новое сообщение из телеграм бота вносилось в новую строчку?
Использую такой метод, но соответственно вносит данные только в теле ячейки, которые указаны в коде.
Пример записи в файл:

```
values = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
body={"valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
      "data": [
      {"range": "A2:F10",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [["This is B3", "This is C3", "This is B3", "This is B3", "This is B3", "This is B3"], ['blating', 'sdsd']]},
      {"range": "D5:E6",
                "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
                "values": [["This is D5", "This is D6"], ["This is E5", "=5+5"]]}]}).execute()`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, вдруг кому пригодится.

```
import gspread # pip install gspread 


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='ваш креденшел файл.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('Ваш sheet ID')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


transaction = ['столбец А', 'столбец Б', 'столбец В']


worksheet.append_row(transaction) # каждый раз при добавлении списка в таблицу, данные будут вносится на пустую строку вниз.
```